# Text Masking with Background Fixed (like parallax effect)

Tags: html, css

I want to mask text with Fixed background image just like this:

https://hitachiglobalweb.plasticbcn.com/

(scroll to bottom --> that air written text masking effect )

I can make a text mask but unable to get that Fixed Background for parallax effect.

There are many tricks to achieve text masking, but none have example of fixed background.
i have tried all these and also tried to give fixed background.

https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/

```
<div class="vert_clip_cont">
  <div class="vert_clip mask two">CNC</div>
</div>


.vert_clip_cont {
    position: relative;
}
.vert_clip {

transform: rotate(-90deg);
font-size: 190px;
font-weight: 800;
padding: 0px 0;
background: url(../images/fi.png);
background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-size: 100% auto;
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
}
```

So, I know how to mask text but unable to background: Fixed;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is not enough space for the background to be fixed, try using `min-height`
I made a fiddle for you check it https://jsfiddle.net/je85nw7v/11/

Comment: sir, its not working. even there in no text masking

Comment: It is working for me, I am using chrome 75 on windows 10

Comment: it is working on jsFiddle.net when I am using chrome 75 because the website depends on the browser, I don't know for other versions of browsers how it will work.

Comment: check that screenshot that's how it appears to me https://ibb.co/Lk7Q0mr

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Can you have a sol for that also? I mean how does this website can do this in every browser.

Comment: The website that you showed uses `clip-path` property check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Sir, can you explain why everything in your code disappear when we translate: rotate(-90deg); ?

Comment: If you are having trouble with this, try adding `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` - this helped me when viewing on Chrome